# Order changed when I append values in dictionary from model in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary

I have grouped data according to date and append values to `AppointmentDateModel` - tableValues.
As data contain of one same date with multiple appointments data so I grouped them. 
But when I append values it automatically sorted or rearrange order by itself.

How can I set order as it is in the dictionary so the order cannot be changed? Or am I grouping them in a right way?

My main models are `DownloadEntity` and  `appointmentDownloadModel`  and then for grouped I use `AppointmentDateModel`

declaration:

```
var mDownloadEntity: [DownloadEntity] = []
var tableValues:[AppointmentDateModel] = []
var dict : [Int64:[AppointmentDownloadModel]] = [:]
```

Appending Code:

```
mDownloadEntity.forEach { apDate in
    print(apDate)
    var value = dict[apDate.appdate]
    if(value == nil){
        dict.updateValue([apDate.appointmentDownloadModel!], forKey: apDate.appdate)
    }else{
        value?.append(apDate.appointmentDownloadModel!)
        dict.updateValue(value!, forKey: apDate.appdate)
    }
}

dict.forEach{map in
    let appointmentDateModel = AppointmentDateModel(appointmentDate: map.key, entities:map.value)
    tableValues.append(appointmentDateModel)
}
```

Models:

```
struct AppointmentDownloadModel: Codable{
    var appointmentModel: Appointment
    var progress: Int = 0
    var failedList: [Int: String] = [:]
    var isFinished: Bool = false
}

struct DownloadEntity: Codable {

    let id: Int
    var appdate: Int64
    var userId: Int
    var dFirmId: Int
    var appointmentId: Int
    var appointmentDownloadModel: AppointmentDownloadModel?
}

struct AppointmentDateModel: Codable {
    let appointmentDate:Int64
    var entities:[AppointmentDownloadModel]
}
```

Comment: Dictionary is not an ordered structure, you need to order your array after extraction again

Comment: @ReinierMelian Thank you, possible for you to show me any example of my code ?

Comment: Simply sort the array after all elements has been added, `tableValues.sort(by: {$0. appointmentDate}`. Off topic but should look into using `Dictionary(grouping:by:)` when creating your dictionary.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I have implemented sorted but giving two error.  `Cannot convert value of type 'Int64' to closure result type 'Bool' `
and second this: `Contextual closure type '(AppointmentDateModel, AppointmentDateModel) throws -> Bool' expects 2 arguments, but 1 was used in closure body`

Comment: Yes, a typo on my part. `{$0.appointmentDate < $1.appointmentDate}`. You could try to look this up in the documentation as well

Answer (score 1):

for have an ordered dictionary, you can add the Swift package manager : swift-collections and add the import OrderedCollections and use the OrderedDictionary object

https://github.com/apple/swift-collections